# Align views on LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android, json, android-layout, user-interface, android-linearlayout

I am developing a ListView UI after parsing a json, We are looking for a template based solution to list row where each list row might have different-2 field and their alignment which will be driven by server in the form of json.
I have parsed my JSON and developed row for ListView, like below

[image]

But I am not able to align my views in linearLayout,
like Name should be in most left and rest views should be right aligned for example we have done in this by XML UI.

[image]

Can anybody help me to align these viwes in upper listView in LinearLayout Like my XML view.

I am adding several linearLayout with horizontal orientation and adding all the child views in these layouts, after adding all children I add this layout in one another LinearLayout with vertical orientation.

I have been tried

passing RelativeLayout and LinearLayout qualified params for alignment while adding views in LinearLayout but it does not work, I can add views either from left or from right only.

here is my code where I tried to add views to create a row for List.

```
public class RowLayout extends LinearLayout{
    Context context;
Hashtable<String, LinearLayout> ht = new Hashtable<String, LinearLayout>();
LinearLayout ll;
WorkkardData workkardData=null;
public RowLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context=context;
}

public LinearLayout generateLayout(Object object, WorkkardData workkard){
    this.workkardData=workkard;
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject)object;
    String template="";
    String cardBackground="";
    String cardSelectedBackground="";
    String fieldName="";
    try {
        template = json.getString("templateId");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    try {
        cardBackground = json.getString("backgroundColor");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        cardSelectedBackground = json.getString("selectedBackgroundColor");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        cardBackground = json.getString("backgroundColor");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    LinearLayout workkardrowLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    workkardrowLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    workkardrowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(cardBackground));

    RoundRectShape roundRect = new RoundRectShape(new float[]{10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10}, null, null);

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]{Color.parseColor(cardBackground), Color.parseColor("#F0F5F4")});
    gd.setStroke(1, Color.parseColor("#b4bdbf"));
    workkardrowLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);

    try {
        JSONArray childrentop = json.getJSONArray("children");
        for (int i = 0; i < childrentop.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray subChildren = childrentop.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("children");

            String width="350", height="0", rightAlignmen="0";
            int widthInt=0;
            try {
                width = childrentop.getJSONObject(i).getString("width");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                height = childrentop.getJSONObject(i).getString("height");
                System.out.println("height::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"+height);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                rightAlignmen = childrentop.getJSONObject(i).getString("rightAlign");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(width.equalsIgnoreCase("100%")){
                widthInt = 350;
            }else{
                widthInt = 350*(Integer.parseInt(width.trim().split("%")[0]))/100;
            }

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsll1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widthInt,Integer.parseInt(height.trim()));
            ll = new LinearLayout(context);
            if(subChildren.length()==0){
                ht.put("i", ll);
                workkardrowLayout.addView((View) ht.get("i"));
            }else{
                TextView[] textView = new TextView[3];
                for (int j = 0; j < subChildren.length(); j++) {

                    String type = "", field= "", backgroundColor ="", textColor ="", alignment ="",horizontalPadding ="", bold="",widthChild="",textColorChild="",fontSize="",style="lower";
                    try {
                        type = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("type");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        field = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("field");
                        fieldName=field;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        backgroundColor = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("backgroundColor");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        textColor = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("textColor");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        alignment = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("alignment");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        horizontalPadding = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("horizontalPadding");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        bold = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("bold");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        widthChild = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("width");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        textColorChild = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("textColor");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        fontSize = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("fontSize");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        style = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("style");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    int padding=0;
                    try {
                        padding = Integer.parseInt(horizontalPadding);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llChild = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsll2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    if(rightAlignmen.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                        llChild.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                    }

                    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("label")){
                        TextView listText1 = new TextView(context);
                        if(field.equalsIgnoreCase("workkardNumber")){
                            listText1.setId(1234);
                            textView[0]=listText1;
                        }
                        if(style.equalsIgnoreCase("upper")){
                            //listText1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                            listText1.setText(this.getWorkkardMethod(field).toUpperCase());
                        }else{
                            listText1.setText(this.getWorkkardMethod(field));
                        }
                        if(field.equalsIgnoreCase("lossDate")){
                            listText1.setText("Loss Date:"+this.getWorkkardMethod(field));
                            paramsll2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                        }
                        if(field.equalsIgnoreCase("reportedDate")){
                            listText1.setText("Reported:"+this.getWorkkardMethod(field));
                            paramsll2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                        }
                        if (!backgroundColor.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            ShapeDrawable roundRect1=new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(new float[]{10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10}, null, null));
                            roundRect1.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));
                            listText1.setBackgroundDrawable(roundRect1);
                        }
                        listText1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(textColor));
                        if (!fontSize.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            listText1.setTextSize(Integer.parseInt(fontSize));
                        }
                        listText1.setPadding(padding,padding, padding, padding);
                        if(alignment.equalsIgnoreCase("left")){
                            paramsll2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                        }
                        if(alignment.equalsIgnoreCase("right")){
                            llChild.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;
                        }
                        if(alignment.equalsIgnoreCase("centre")){
                            paramsll2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                        }
                        if(bold.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                            listText1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        }
                            ll.addView(listText1);
                            ll.setLayoutParams(paramsll2);
                    }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("spacer")){
                        TextView listText1 = new TextView(context);
                        listText1.setWidth(Integer.parseInt(widthChild));
                        listText1.setText("");
                        ll.addView(listText1);
                    }
                }
                ht.put("i", ll);
                workkardrowLayout.addView((View) ht.get("i"));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return workkardrowLayout;
}
String getWorkkardMethod(String fieldName){
    String work="";
    if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("template")){
        work=workkardData.getTemplate();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("workkardTitle")){
        work=workkardData.getWorkkardTitle();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("workkardDescription")){
        work=workkardData.getWorkkardDescription();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("workType")){
        work=workkardData.getWorkType();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("workkardNumber")){
        work=workkardData.getWorkkardNumber();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("claimantName")){
        work=workkardData.getClaimantName();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("reportedDate")){
        work=workkardData.getReportedDate();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("lossDate")){
        work=workkardData.getLossDate();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("lossType")){
        work=workkardData.getLossType();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("address")){
        work=workkardData.getAddress();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("county")){
        work=workkardData.getCounty();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("state")){
        work=workkardData.getState();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("zip")){
        work=workkardData.getZip();
    }
    return work;
}
}
```

Comment: I did not found any  solution yet, I am a bit low, help me to find solution.

Comment: why don't you inflate some layout file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puneet I am glad to help you, you are overriding same Layout params every time when you add a view in Layout, I wrote a code for you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayouts.Builder builder;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ImageView iv1=new ImageView(this.getApplicationContext());
    iv1.setId(1);
    iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    ImageView iv2=new ImageView(this.getApplicationContext());
    iv2.setId(2);
    iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.pdf);

    ImageView iv3=new ImageView(this.getApplicationContext());
    iv3.setId(3);
    iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.pictureicon);

    ImageView iv4=new ImageView(this.getApplicationContext());
    iv4.setId(4);
    iv4.setImageResource(R.drawable.login_btn);


    RelativeLayout rl =new RelativeLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsrl = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    rl.setLayoutParams(paramsrl);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsrl1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsrl1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    iv1.setLayoutParams(paramsrl1);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsrl2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsrl2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1);
    iv2.setLayoutParams(paramsrl2);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsrl3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsrl3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    iv3.setLayoutParams(paramsrl3);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsrl4 = new     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsrl4.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, 3);
    iv4.setLayoutParams(paramsrl4);

    rl.addView(iv1, paramsrl1);
    rl.addView(iv2, paramsrl2);
    rl.addView(iv3, paramsrl3);
    rl.addView(iv4, paramsrl4);
    setContentView(rl);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `params.gravity` to make your alignment for `LinearLayout`. Example code given below.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL; 
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```